# Multiple Meta Boxes in separate files

Tags: metabox

So here's the problem, I want to have a few different meta boxes on my sites, but I'd like to be able to store each of them in separate files and included them into functions, so I can just copy specific ones to new installs and included them on a case by case basis.

From what I can gather though, it seems like I need to put them all into one array?

Comment: Have you seen this at all? http://voodoopress.com/2011/04/building-a-meta-box-with-the-deluxe-blog-tips-framework/  I've been playing around with it recently and really dig it. I can use it to set up any possible meta box I could want (text, wysiwyg, image, etc). You then just set up site specific meta box instances in your functions.php.

Comment: the answer really depends on your setup and code. so provide some.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save each meta box out to a file with the code as if they were in your functions.php file. Maybe place these in a folder called meta_boxes. Then to include into your theme just `include()` them into your functions file

```
<?php
// all the code that your functions file contains
include("meta_boxes/meta1.php");
include("meta_boxes/meta2.php");
include("meta_boxes/meta3.php");
include("meta_boxes/meta4.php");
// As so on....
?>
```

Comment: When I do that it only shows the last included item.

Comment: By any chance you are repeating function names in both or more files?

Comment: I didn't think I was, but I guess I must be if it's supposed to work.

Here's the two functions I'm trying to create. 

http://www.leschinskidesign.com.php5-10.websitetestlink.com/test/metaone.txt


http://www.leschinskidesign.com.php5-10.websitetestlink.com/test/metatwo.txt

Comment: `$prefix` and `$meta_box` are getting overridden by the last include. Instead name them `$prefix1`, `$prefix2` and so on for each meta box include